# iOS 11 navigationitem large title not expand/Collapasing properly for TabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios11

TabBarController(Root) -> I have 5 view controllers(), each view controllers pushed with UINavigationControlller for navigationBar and large title -> from one of this view controller didSelectRowAt() pushing another -> TabBarController2 -> It has again 5 viewControllers(), here no need to push with navigationController for navBar and largeTitle as it is inheriting from the previous. This is setup now the problem is

TabBarController(root)->Large title expand/Collapsing(for all viewControllers)-didSelectRow->TabBarController2->ViewController(1)-largeTitle expand/Collapsing well. ->Tap on another viewControllers try scroll, large title is not able to expand/Collapse(Note I had tableView with enough rows for scroll), and if I just rotated device(i.e orientation changed) then It is working as expected for all orientation. It seems something issue with iOS-11...11.2. Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this in your first view controller,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true 
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
} }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it is not resolving this issue.